# Cloudflare Tunnel RDP Connection

Tags: cloudflare, rdp, ngrok, tunnel

So I have computers A and B (both are windows and behind NAT) and I need to connect B via RDP from A. Following this [official document from cloudflare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/use-cases/rdp/#connect-to-rdp-server-with-cloudflared-access), I can do this. However, I need to setup access on computer A too rather than directly connect to rdp.example.com.

I'm wondering if there is way to let me directly connect to rdp.example.com instead of having to setup access on computer A first. I think ngrok could achieve this, not sure if cloudflare tunnel has a way. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using an ssh tunnel you can achieve this. However, since B is behind NAT, you could use some tunnelling service. Here is how to quickly test it using https://pinggy.io:

Run the following command on B:

```
ssh -p 443 -R0:localhost:8000 tcp@a.pinggy.io
```

This will output a hostname and a port such as:

```
tcp://rangonwopwjdc.a.pinggy.io:42758
```

From A you can now connect to `rangonwopwjdc.a.pinggy.io:42758`

If you have an account in [pinggy](https://pinggy.io) then you can also find the tunnel address from the dashboard.

I believe similar service is provided by ngrok where you need to download and install ngrok in B.